# Application not loading as Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.1, docker-machine

I am trying my hands on `Dockering` `ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC` application.

I have created a Vanilla MVC template project which has no build error.

This is how my `DockerFile` looks like

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

EXPOSE 80 #As suggested in the comment

COPY . ./docker-aspnet-app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Creating Docker image

```
F:\Some\dev\www\docker\sample-app\sample-app>docker build -t aspnetapp .
```

Creating Container

```
docker run -d -p 8084:80 --name aspnetwebapp aspnetapp
```

[image]

But when I browse localhost:8084 the website is not loading

[image]

**How do I address this?**

*Please note I am running Docker in Linux Mode on my windows10 machine*

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with dotnet mv myself, does it start on port 80 with the command: `dotnet publish -c Release -o out`?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort, dotnet mvc is similar to any other framework web application. It can run on any available web port

Comment: And in your case you are sure that within your image it runs on port 80?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort Sorry! didn't get your latest comment.

Comment: If you execute the command you specified in the `RUN` statement, does that start your application where it is listening on port 80?

Comment: If you look into the screenshot that you have attached you can see the container has exited when you run docker la --all command, which means your container is not running due to an error, so it cannot be accessed.

Seems like there a issue in your Dockerfile. Double check it, when you run docker ls --all you should see its running.

Comment: @RavinduFernando, Agreed I got an eye on the same & has same understanding. But if that's the case why it's exiting. I have shared the compelte DockerFile here

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `Dockerfile` should `EXPOSE` port 80, try adding `EXPOSE 80` to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Updated the DockerFile as you suggested. Please check the question. Sorry! still the same errror

Answer (score 0):

## Here is an example with using port 3000:

Try using "docker-compose up", instead of "docker run ...".
You need to put "EXPOSE 3000" in your Docker file.
You will need a docker-compose.yml file with contents like this example:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  webapp:
    image: webapp
    build: .
    environment:
       NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Comment: `ports` in **docker-compose** and `-p` in **docker run** practically behave in the same way (except docker-compose adds an Alias inside the network to be accessed by other containers). I don't think that this is a solution for this question.